# It is returning none while scraping the data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

when i am using the findAll with corrrect class and tag it is returning None ans sometime empty list when i change the class..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
s=requests.get('https://ineuron.ai/courses')
soup=bs(s.text,'html.parser')
t=soup.find('div',{"class":"AllCoursesMobile_course-filter-mobile__atbp2"})
print(t)
```

I want to extract all the data from  particular class

Comment: I want to extract the course detail from the website and for that i have written it's class name , but when i am executing the code it is returning the none

Comment: website is dynamic, try selenium.

Comment: @СергейКох Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned content is rendered dynamically and `requests` only deals with static content - Take a look at the devloper tools of the browser and check the XHR request that is fired to get the course information:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.json_normalize(pd.read_json('https://ineuron.ai/_next/data/RCswhPX7tXYKTfUB0-2MP/courses.json')['pageProps']['initialState']['filter']['initCourses'])
```